# Empty Container ID in GoogleTagManager module for Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, google-tag-manager

1. I installed and enabled this module https://www.drupal.org/project/google_tag
   (ver. 7.x-1.2).
2. I entered my **GTM-XXXXXXX** in the **Container ID** field.
3. I saved the configuration.

The code is added to the page but **Container ID** is missing.

```
[...] (window,document,'script','dataLayer','');</script>

<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=" [...]
```

Does anybody know what the reason might be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem when I updated the plugin. If you have i18n enabled you need use multilingual varible. Enable Container ID from /admin/config/regional/i18n/variable.